# PostgreSQL: Role clearly exists but does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I wanted to tidy up the roles in my postgreSQL database, when I stumbled upon one role I never consciously created. I supposed it has something to do with the Linux user that hosts the database, but oddly the system pretends the user does not exist when I try to alter or drop the role.

```
select * from pg_roles;
rolname    | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcatupdate | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolconfig |  oid
---------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------
postgreSQL    | t        | t          | t             | t           | t            | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               |           | 16387
postgres      | t        | t          | t             | t           | t            | t           | t              |           -1 | ********    |               |           |    10
standard_wimi | f        | t          | f             | f           | f            | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               |           | 17992 enter code here
```

So, postgres is my superuser and standard_wimi a role I just created. At first I tried to drop the role postgreSQL, because it seems I don't need it and therefore I think it should not be there (with these kind of privileges). But any attempt to drop or alter the role yields this:

```
ALTER ROLE postgreSQL NOLOGIN;
ERROR:  role "postgresql" does not exist
```

Can somebody please explain this behavior to me? Where does the role come from and why is psql pretending it doesn't exist?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roles are case sensitive and every case sensitive identifier that is not delimited is cast to lowercase.

```
ALTER ROLE "postgreSQL" NOLOGIN;
```